# Read String line by line after read from file in assets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I can read the file successfully, but only one part of the lines was processed. As you can see: split the raw string by the method split of String class, I do not know why. Is there another way to split String into lines?

```
String rawStr = rootBundle.loadString('assets/sql/create_tables');
List<String> list = rawStr.split("\n");
list.map( (e) {
    print("> $e");
    db.execute(e);
});
```

I expect all the lines will be processed.

**The code read from assets and process line by line should be as follows.**

```
    String rawStr = rootBundle.loadString('assets/sql/create_tables');
Iterable<String> list = LineSplitter.split(rawStr);
list.forEach((e){
if (e?.isEmpty ?? true) {
    //Do nothing
} else {
    print("> $e");
    db.execute(e);
}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

try using `forEach()` as seen below.

```
list.forEach((e){
   print("> $e");
   db.execute(e);
});
```

Good Luck.

Comment: I changed my code as you suggested, it work. Thank you very much! And I split the string by a new method: LineSplitter.split

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can read the strings using LineSplitter:

```
  void _loadFile() async {
    String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/myfile.txt');
    LineSplitter.split(data).forEach((line) => print('$line'));
  }
```

Replace print with your data loading function.